# curves in varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $V$ be an affine  algebraic variety defined over $\mathbb R$. 
We assume that $V\subset \mathbb A_n$(affine $n$ space).
Suppose that for any algebraic curve $C$ in $V$ defined over $\mathbb R$, the real points $C(\mathbb R)$   is contained in a finite union of proper  affine $\mathbb R$-subspaces of $\mathbb A_n$. Is it true that $V(\mathbb R)$ is contained in a finite union of affine $\mathbb R $-subspaces of $\mathbb A_n$.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, the answer is no: what if $V$ is a real plane cubic?

Comment: @Artie: Maybe you are right, but that's not what I want to know.  The question is modified.

Comment: Dear ronggang, ok. In that case, it seems like another title might be more suitable.

Comment: @Artie: I agree. It seems rational relates to open subsets of affine space in algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. We can assume without loss of generality that the real points of $V$ are Zariski dense. Choose some linear projection $\rho: V \to \mathbb R^{\dim V}$ whose image includes some open ball, e.g. a generic linear projection. Then if $L$ is a linear subspace of codimension $1$ in $\mathbb R^n$, $\rho(V \cap L )$ is a variety of dimension at most $\dim V -1$. So we have a $n$-dimensional family of subvarieties of codimension $1$ of this open ball.

Choose a finite set of points of the open ball which is on none of these subvarieties.

Choose a generic curve of high degree passing through the finite set of points. Such a curve will have infinitely many real points, and be irreducible. Or just choose a parametrized curve passing through those points. Since it does not lie in $\rho(V \cap L)$, for any $L$, and is irreducible it intersects $\rho(V \cap L)$ at only finitely many points, so it is contained in no finite union.

Then the inverse image of this curve in $V$ will be contained in the union of no finite set of linear subspaces.